# Unmarshaling INI file using Viper Go is not working as expected

Tags: go, ini, viper-go

I am using viper for app configuration.

Code sample is below.

```golang
package main

import "github.com/spf13/viper"

type Config struct {
    WelcomeMessage string `mapstructure:"message"`
}

func main() {

    viper.SetConfigName("config")
    viper.SetConfigType("ini")
    viper.AddConfigPath(".")
    err := viper.ReadInConfig() // Find and read the config file
    if err != nil {             // Handle errors reading the config file
        //handle error
    }

    // var result map[string]interface{}
    config := Config{}

    err = viper.Unmarshal(&config)
    if err != nil {
        //handle error
    }
    ...

}
```

INI file is simple with single config.

```ini
message=Welcome!
```

I can read configuration value using `viper.Get()` if I use `default.message` as key.

For some reason, `Unmarshal` is not working, meaning that there config variable is struct without value set in WelcomeMessage field.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first mistake is not showing us a minimal reproducer. Specifically, your Go program is missing the relevant `import` statements so I have no idea where the `viper` package comes from. I'm guessing it's https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dvln/viper but the SO community shouldn't have to guess. You also say it "is not working" but don't explain what that means. Again, we shouldn't have to guess what you mean.

Comment: @KurtisRader I have updated import and description. Let's keep comments on constructive instead of disapproving tone. Thank you.

Comment: I was simply pointing out you omitted two crucial pieces of information. It's not my fault you don't know how to ask a good question.

Comment: Given that this question is highly specific to an actively maintained project, rather than a generic programming problem, it seems odd you didn't first open an issue at https://github.com/spf13/viper and only come to SO if the people maintaining, or using, that project did not provide a timely answer.

Comment: @KurtisRader understood. point taken. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The https://github.com/spf13/viper project is woefully under documented. Looking at the source I figured out what is needed to make your code work. The key insight is that the key you are trying to unmarshal is implicitly in a section named "default". So your structure has to put the corresponding variable inside a structure named "Default".

I started by creating a file named *config.ini* with this content:

```
message=Welcome!
hello = goodbye
```

I then put the following code in a file named *x.go*:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"

        "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

type Config struct {
        Default struct {
                WelcomeMessage string `mapstructure:"message"`
                Hello          string
                Undefined      string
        }
}

func main() {

        viper.SetConfigName("config")
        viper.SetConfigType("ini")
        viper.AddConfigPath(".")
        err := viper.ReadInConfig() // Find and read the config file
        if err != nil {             // Handle errors reading the config file
                panic(err)
        }

        // var result map[string]interface{}
        config := Config{}

        err = viper.Unmarshal(&config)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", config)
}
```

Executing "go run x.go" produces this output (which matches what you expect, modulo the need for a nested struct):

```
main.Config{Default:struct { WelcomeMessage string "mapstructure:\"message\""; Hello string; Undefined string }{WelcomeMessage:"Welcome!", Hello:"goodbye", Undefined:""}}
```

P.S., Having gone to the trouble of solving this question, and looking at the Viper project source code (including its unit tests, API and documentation) I **do not recommend** using that project.

P.P.S., The INI file format is like the CSV format. Both were created by Microsoft and were horribly underspecified at the time of their introduction. Resulting in many ambiguities and incompatible implementations. Both formats should be avoided.

Comment: I agree, it has taken too much time to figure all this out. I am taking your point of not using it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What library do you recommend @Kurtis Rader? I was intending to use Viper for a project but realize it's not a good choice.

Comment: @Stratus3D I don't recommend any package for handling INI files because the INI file specification (such as it is) is awful.

Comment: Yep, I agree. But I'm replacing a legacy system and have to parse an INI file. I ended up going with https://ini.unknwon.io/.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `viper` refers to https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dvln/viper then you should read its documentation:

> Q: Why not INI files?
>
> A: Ini files are pretty awful. There’s no standard format, and they
> are hard to validate. Viper is designed to work with JSON, TOML or
> YAML files. If someone really wants to add this feature, I’d be happy
> to merge it. It’s easy to specify which formats your application will
> permit.

Comment: Import I am using states INI files are supported. Yet package you pointed to is fork. Which project is up to date?

Comment: @EnterSB, It is obvious the package you are using is a fork of the one I linked to. The project I linked to hasn't been updated in over seven years whereas the project you grudgingly told us you are using was updated in the past week. They are both "up to date" with respect to each individual project.

Answer (score 1):

After `viper.ReadInConfig` is called, the config is stored in a map like this:

```golang
settings := map[string]any{
    "default": map[string]any{
        "message": "Welcome!",
    },
}
```

So the struct should be defined like this:

```golang
type Config struct {
    Default struct {
        WelcomeMessage string `mapstructure:"message"`
    }
}
```

This is the full example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

type Config struct {
    Default struct {
        WelcomeMessage string `mapstructure:"message"`
    }
}

func main() {
    viper.SetConfigName("config")
    viper.SetConfigType("ini")
    viper.AddConfigPath(".")
    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // To see what is stored.
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", viper.AllSettings())

    config := Config{}

    err = viper.Unmarshal(&config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", config)
}
```

And the output:

```
map[string]interface {}{"default":map[string]interface {}{"message":"Welcome!"}}
{Default:{WelcomeMessage:Welcome!}}
```